# Bind dynamic application configuration into strongly typed model in .Net Core

Tags: json, .net-core

I am trying bind application configuration into strongly typed model. My configuration is dynamically typed so I couldn't figure out how to map configuration into model. Below is the configuration,

**AppSettings.json**

```
{
"Utility": {
    "Log": {
        "FileName": "D:\\Log.txt"
    },
    "test1": {
        "Path": "E:\\Path1",
        "Daystokeep": "0"

    },
    "test2": {
        "Path": "E:\\Path2",
        "Daystokeep": "0"
    },
    "test3": {
        "Path": "E:\\Path3",
        "Daystokeep": "0"
    }
  }
}
```

Here, Log is static and test1, test2 and test3 etc are dynamic. It will be really helpful if you can suggest the possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a dictionary to a configuration property;

```cs
    public class MyConfig {
        public Dictionary<string, Config> Utility { get; set; }
    }
    public class Config {
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public int Daystokeep { get; set; }
    }
```

You can also subclass a dictionary to capture additional values with a fixed structure;

```cs
    public UtilityConfig Utility { get; set; }

    public UtilityConfig : Dictionary<string, Config> {
        public AnotherConfigType Log { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Your answer is almost ok but can you pl see updated JSON which has one of the other static fields which i need to use it as well. Pl update.